# error in XML document (1, 1). when read text file

Tags: xml

I have this code that allows the user to read a text file or XML file
When he chose the text file works correctly, but when he chose XML file
display This error :
error in XML document (1, 1).

this is my code:

```
OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
op.Filter = "XML|*.xml|text|*.txt";

if (op.FilterIndex == 1)
{
    if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        StreamReader Infile = new StreamReader(op.FileName);
        XmlSerializer Des = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<classname>));
        Program.ListStudent = (List<classname>)Des.Deserialize(Infile);
        Infile.Close();
    }
}
else
{
    if (op.FilterIndex == 2)
    {
        if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamReader Infile = new StreamReader(op.FileName);
            string header = Infile.ReadLine();

            while (!Infile.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = Infile.ReadLine();
                string[] parts = line.Split(new char[] { '\t' }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                s.Id = Convert.ToInt64(parts[0]);
                s.Fname = parts[1];
                s.Lname = parts[2];
                Program.ListStudent.Add(s);
            }
            Infile.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

this is the XML file

```html
   
  <ArrayOfStudent xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">; <Student> <Id>12345</Id> <Fname>Mohammad</Fname> <Lname>Ali</Lname> </Student> </ArrayOfStudent>
```

Comment: sorry My mistake it's 2 and the same problem

Comment: Need to see the actual xml being read in, but first guess is that it's missing xml prolog,  First line of XML may be expected to be: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: Do not put that in comments. You need to [edit] your question and add it there, where it can be seen and properly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

First of all, your XML seems to be invalid, I don't know were you are getting the ';' from but they shouldn't be there....

Here is some code that will deserialise your XML to a List

Usings

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
```

Classes

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Student")]
public class Student
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fname")]
    public string Fname { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Lname")]
    public string Lname { get; set; }
}
```

code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            List<Student> deserializedList = new List<Student>();
            deserializedList = Deserialize<List<Student>>();

        }// Put a break-point here, then mouse-over deserializedList
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    private static T Deserialize<T>() where T : new()
    {
        // Create an instance of T
        T ReturnListOfT = CreateInstance<T>();


        // Create a new file stream for reading the XML file
        using (FileStream ReadFileStream = new FileStream("xml.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            // Construct a XmlSerializer and use it  
            // to serialize the data from the stream.
            XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            try
            {
                // Deserialize the hashtable from the file
                ReturnListOfT = (T)SerializerObj.Deserialize(ReadFileStream);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to serialize. Reason: {0}", ex.Message));
            }

        }
        // return the Deserialized data.
        return ReturnListOfT;
    }

    // function to create instance of T
    public static T CreateInstance<T>() where T : new()
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

And here is what your XML should look like

```
<ArrayOfStudent xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Student>
    <Id>12345</Id>
    <Fname>Mohammad</Fname>
    <Lname>Ali</Lname>
</Student>
</ArrayOfStudent>
```

Save the XML to a file called xml.xml in the same folder as your application *.exe